# Import HTML file into another HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to import HTML file into HTML.
I need something like this:

```
<div>
  <iframe  onload="iframe.document.head.appendChild(ifstyle)" name="log" src="Objects.html"></iframe>
  <style>
  iframe {
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

But `<iframe>` crushes all the code in the main HTML file and causes thousands of errors like:

> Error:  attribute points: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "…5390592086273 0 ".

Also:

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame at HTMLIFrameElement.onload

So I need to put HTML into another HTML and style it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the  element to link files from HTML, CSS, or javascript:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<link herf="blah.html">
</body>
</html>
```